# Add default value to a list/map

Tags: java

I have this code that get's the amount of users per day in the application.

```
    List<UserApplication> usersOfCurrentMonth = userApplicationRepository.getUsersOfCurrentMonth();

    Map<Object, Long> dailyUserActivity = usersOfCurrentMonth.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a-> ((UserApplication)a).getCreationDate(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Query

```
@Query(value = "select * from user_application a where year(a.creationDate) = year(current_date) and  month(a.creationDate) = month(current_date)", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserApplication> getUsersOfCurrentMonth();
```

Works well

```
2020-03-30T14:21:09.003+0000: 1
```

But **I am missing the rest of the days of the month**. Is there a way to add 0 to all the other days of the month?

e.g.

```
 2020-03-01T14:21:09.003+0000: 0
 2020-03-02T14:21:09.003+0000: 0
 ....
 2020-03-30T14:21:09.003+0000: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the number of days in the current month and then make a loop over all days, setting the result to zero with [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: Right, don't need to invent something - it is a good solution